# In MEF, How to avoid unnecessary type scanning for exports using DirectoryCatalog to improve the performance?

Tags: c#-4.0, mef

I have around 20 dlls, exports, imports the parts. Have a class in each dll, with import and export attributes. But while composing MEF scans all the types available in the dll.

Result below is taken from just one dll's output.

Due to this, compose method takes time. How to avoid unnecessary type scanning?

```
    sample plugin

[ModuleAttibute("MENU")]
[ExportMetadata("SAMPLE", "SAMPLE")]
public class MenuModule : IModule
{
}

    public static bool CheckParts(ComposablePartDefinition partDef)
    {
        var keepPart = (from e in partDef.ExportDefinitions
                        where e.Metadata.ContainsKey("Sample")
                        select e).Any();

        return keepPart;
    }


public class FilteredCatalog : ComposablePartCatalog
{
    private readonly ComposablePartCatalog _inner;
    private readonly Func<ComposablePartDefinition,bool> _partsQuery;

    public FilteredCatalog(ComposablePartCatalog inner, Func<ComposablePartDefinition, bool> expression)
    {
        _inner = inner;
        _partsQuery = expression;
    }

    public override IQueryable<ComposablePartDefinition> Parts
    {
        get
        {
            return FilterParts();
        }
    }

    public  IQueryable<ComposablePartDefinition> FilterParts()
    {
        return (from p in _inner.Parts
                let keepPart = _partsQuery(p)
                where keepPart == true
                select p);
    }
}

var cat1 = new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"].Replace("~", exeDirectory), "*PlugIn*.dll");

var filteredCat1 = new FilteredCatalog(cat1, CheckParts);
_catalog.Catalogs.Add(filteredCat1);
var cc1 = new CompositionContainer(_catalog);
cc1.ComposeParts(this);
```

**results**

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.DbTypes' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.EnvironmentInfo' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.Interfaces.IHost' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.Interfaces.IModule' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.Interfaces.IPlugIn' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.Interfaces.IModuleAttribute' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.Interfaces.IModuleHandler' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.Interfaces.ISNLogin' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.ModuleAttibute' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.FilteredCatalog' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'PlugIn.Core.PlugInBase' was ignored because it contains no exports.

System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'OneSystem.Shell.Properties.Resources' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'OneSystem.Shell.Properties.Settings' was ignored because it contains no exports.
```

another plugin output, which took 2000 miliseconds on compose. totally 400 types scanned in the project.

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.AppLauncher' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.Bootstrapper' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.FrmMap' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.FrmOverView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.IArrivalDetailsView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.ucArrivalDetails' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.ArrivalDetailsPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.ICargoPortDetailsView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.ucCargoPortDetails' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.CargoPortDetailsPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.IGeneralPortAgentInfoView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.ucPortAgentInfo' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.PortAgentInfoPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.IPieChartActivitiesFactsView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.ucPieChartActivities' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.PieChartActivitiesFactsPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.IPortAlertsView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.ucPortAlerts' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.PortAlertsPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.IVRSView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.ucVRS' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.OverView.VRSPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.iPositionExplorer' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.FrmPositionExplorerNew' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.FrmAdjustSpeed' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.ICargoDialogView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.frmCargoDialogBox' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.FormPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.FrmCreateDADesk' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.FrmCreateDADeskByAgent' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.FrmCreateDADeskByAgentPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.IFrmCreateDADeskByAgentView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.FrmDebunker' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.LogAbstractDialogFormView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.frmLogAbstractDialogBox' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.FormLogAbstractPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PerformanceDetailsDialogView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.frmPerformanceDialogBox' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PerformanceDetailsDialogPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.FrmPortCallBunkerDetail' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.FrmROEDialogBox' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.FrmSteamDialogBox' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.IFrmAdjustROBView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.FrmAdjustROB' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.FrmAdjustROBPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.FrmBrowser' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.FrmUpdateDADesk' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorerNewPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.IUserControlView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.ITabView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucFixtureNote' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.FixtureNotePresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.LogAbstractView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucLogAbstract' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.LogAbstractPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ILogAbstractDetailView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.IPositionDetailTab' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucLogAbstractDetails' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.LogAbstractDetailPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PerformanceDetailsView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucPerformanceDetails' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PerformanceDetailsPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.IPortCallActivityView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.ucPortCallActivities' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PortCallActivityPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.IPortCallBunkerDetailView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.IPortBunkerDetOuterView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.ucPortCallBunkerDetail' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PortCallBunkerDetailPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ICommentsView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucPortCallComments' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PortCallCommentsPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.IPortCallDAView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucPortCallDA' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PortCallDAPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.IPortCallFactView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucPortCallFact' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PortCallFactPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.IPortCallHistory' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.UcPortCallHistory' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PortCallHistoryPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ITaskView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucPortCallTask' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.TaskPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.UcArrDepPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.IUcArrDepView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ICargoFactView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucCargoFacts' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.CargoFactPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PortBunkerPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.IPortBunkerView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.ICargoView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.ucCargoes' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.CargoPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.IUserControlView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.ucPortLogCargo' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.ucPortLogCargoPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.ClonePositionCargo' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.IPositionSearchAdditionalView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucPositionSearchAdditional' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PositionSearchAdditionalPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.IPositionSearchBasicView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucPositionSearchBasic' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.PositionSearchBasicPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.IUpdateDADeskView' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.ucUpdateDADesk' was ignored because it contains no exports.
System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'ERP.VM.UI.PositionExplorer.UpdateDADeskPresenter' was ignored because it contains no exports.
```

Answer (score 5):

To eliminate scanning, you can replace the `DirectoryCatalog` by a `TypeCatalog` like this:

```
var cat1 = new TypeCatalog(typeof(Type1), typeof(Type2), ...);
```

However, you probably want the plugins to be discovered automatically. That's why you are using `DirectoryCatalog` in the first place right? And this can't be done without actually scanning all the types to see which ones are exported.

Are you sure that it is the scanning which is taking a lot of time? Perhaps it is the `CheckParts` code (not shown in your question) which is slowing things down. Try removing the use of `FilteredCatalog` to check its effect on performance.

**edit**: I just realized that you are probably building the composition container many times, which is why the 2 second load time is not acceptable. The fix is to **build the composition container only once at application start-up**.

Comment: i need to discover dlls automatically. so need Directorycatalog.  after removing filter logic, took same time. composing container with UI plughin (which has more types, output shown in above), took around 2000k milliseconds. without UI plugIn, with simple dll took only 700 milliseconds. so on compose, scanning for exports in all the types takes time. so if TypeCatalog + DirectoryCatalog would solve this?

Comment: composing only once at application start up. actually i am converting existing application (exe to dll) as plugin. actuallly now Loading responsibility moved separately, which finds the plugins and loads them. checked with stopwatch on compose method with different plugins. looks like, compose method execution varies depends on no of types the plug-in contains. plug-in with 40 types, compose method took 600ms. plug-in with 360 types, it took 2000 ms.